# Not able to Mock Java method call using Spock

Tags: java, spock

I am trying to mock my following java method using Spock.

```java
        public List<DiffEntry> listDifferences(String oldCommit, String newCommit, Git git)
          throws GitAPIException, RevisionSyntaxException, AmbiguousObjectException,
          IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException {

        logger.info(
            "Inside DiffCommits#listDifferences to calculating difference commits refs {}  and {} ",
            oldCommit, newCommit);

        ObjectId oldTree = git.getRepository().resolve(oldCommit);
        ObjectId newTree = git.getRepository().resolve(newCommit);

        if (oldTree == null || newTree == null) {
          logger.warn(
              "Could not resolve either old {} or new commits {}, difference cant not be calculated",
              oldCommit, newCommit);
          throw new RefNotFoundException("Unable to resolve tag reference. Invalid tag provided");
        }

        ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
        CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        oldTreeIter.reset(reader, oldTree);

        CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
        newTreeIter.reset(reader, newTree);

        DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

        df.setRepository(git.getRepository());
        List<DiffEntry> entries;
        entries = df.scan(newTreeIter, oldTreeIter);
        df.close();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
          for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            logger.debug("Entry: " + entries.get(i));
          }
        }

        return entries;
      }
```

Everything is working fine but the mocking of following code get failed

```java
DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```

And getting error at

```
df.setRepository(git.getRepository());
```

The error that I am getting is

```
> org.eclipse.jgit.lib.StoredConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9a2f8398 cannot be
> cast to org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffConfig java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.eclipse.jgit.lib.StoredConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9a2f8398 cannot be
> cast to org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffConfig  at
> org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.setReader(DiffFormatter.java:201)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter.setRepository(DiffFormatter.java:180)
>   at
> com.sf.bt.mdm.subscription.scmdiff.DiffCommits.listDifferences(DiffCommits.java:65)
>   at com.sf.bt.mdm.subscription.service.DiffCommitSpec.test list
> differences(DiffCommitSpec.groovy:59)
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Pass it to your method, or make it a class variable that you pass by the constructor. This way you can pass a mock and your method will be using the mock.

Comment: @Bentaye is there another way ?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: @Bentaye error updated in question

Answer (score 0):

```
DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```

This code is problematic from the point of view of unit testing. Its not a dependency so it can't be injected in the class. So basically you're trying to mock a constructor (`new`) object.

Technically the only way you can try is using Global Mocks and create spies wrapping the real object: Read the [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#MockingConstructors). These are not regular spock's Mocks and Stubs.

However I believe there are other approaches. After all the link I've sent you starts with "think twice before using..." for a reason ;)

1. You've by yourself decided to put this object creation inside the method, which is ok. However this means that you do not treat this `DiffFormatter` as a real dependency. So maybe even in unit test you should let it run, concentrating on mocking its input parameters themselves? Just the same holds also for `ByteArrayOutputStream`. This plays nicely in general with the concept that the code should be written in a way that unit tests should not really care about the internal implementation of the methods. Always prefer blackbox testing to white-box testing.
2. Alternatively if you think its a dependency, then maybe you should make it a data field. Then You could inject it into the test with a regular mocks. If this class should be created per method invocation, you can inject `Supplier<DiffFormatter> and in method` just call it's get method, it will act as a factory.

Comment: Global mocks will **not** work for Java code under test, only for Groovy code. The class under test ought to be refactored for better testability according to your suggestion to make the dependency injectable or to at least factor its creation out into a stubbable helper method. Otherwise some tool like PowerMock must be used which IMO would be a code smell.